# split function in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have an array which contains different values, i want split them off and print in browser. but i want alert it first value. i have made a function but it is not wokring

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var jam= new Array("first","second","third","fourth");
    var Klnew= jam.split(",");

    //for(i=0;i<Klnew.length;i++) {}

    alert(Klnew[0])     
});    
</script>
```

Comment: `split` is the function of `String`,not of `Array`.

Comment: i'm also wondering what should happen if you call split on an array :D

Comment: @sdepold. ohhh, please don't, **the world will come to it's end!**

Comment: @gdoron :D it could probably return an array of arrays. so every string inside the array gets split :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $(function(){
        var jam= new Array("first","second","third","fourth");
        var Klnew= jam.slice();
    //  for(i=0;i<Klnew.length;i++) {}
        alert(Klnew[0])
   })
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't split an array. It is already split.

You might be looking for something like this:

```
var foo = ['a', 'b', 'c']; 
console.log(foo.shift());    // Outputs "a"
console.log(foo.join(','));  // Outputs "b,c"
```

… but it hard to tell what your goals are from your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
var jam= new Array("first","second","third","fourth");
alert(jam[0]); // alert before the join.
var Klnew= jam.join(","); // join, not split the array...
```

**Output:**

```
"first,second,third,fourth"
```

Comment: ok thanks but now i want split them and print using document.write

Comment: @Quentin. I meant `join`, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You would use split for getting an array out of a string:

> "first,second,third,fourth".split(',') ==> ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']

Answer (score 0):

even this is going to work--

```
var jam = new Array("first", "second", "third", "fourth");
alert(jam[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`split` (of string) method splits string to array.

`join` (of array) method joins array elements into string.
So:

```
arr = Array("first","second","third","fourth");
str = arr.join(",")
alert(str) // will alert "first,second,third,fourth"
alert(arr == str.split(","))// will alert true
```

Comment: The second alert is false because both sides are objects and therefore must return false by [definition](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3).